# clickable circle on canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I was trying to create LUDO game in python for that I've created the coins using tkinter but now I'm unable to make it clickable button as it's int

```
self.r1 = self.create_canvas.create_oval(67, 58, 91, 83, width = 3, fill = "#ff0000")
```

now help me this `coin` act as `btn`

I want it to move when clicked.

Comment: canvas has special methods to detect if some area overlaps some objects. So you have to get mouse position and use ie (mouse_x, mouse_y, mouse_x+1, mouse_y+1)` to check if it overlap some object and check if it is `self.r1`

Comment: See [Canvas.find_overlaping](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method). It may need also `cavnas.bind('<Button-1>', function)` to run function when you click left mouse's button on canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `canvas.tag_bind(tag, event, callback)` to execute function (callback) when you click (event `<Button-1>`) on item with selected tag or ID (`self.r1`)

Other method is to bind `<Button-1>` to canvas and later use `event.x`,`event.y` with `canvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x+1, y+1)` to find all item which overlap region `(x, y, x+1, y+1)` and check if `self.r1 in list_with_overlaping`

You can use `canvas.move(tag, offset_x, offset_y)` or `canvas.moveto(tag, x, y)` to move object.

---

Minimal working code with both methods:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- functions ---

def on_canvas_click(event):
    print('on canvas click')

    print('event:', event)
    print('x, y :', event.x, event.y)
    overlaping = canvas.find_overlapping(event.x, event.y, event.x+1, event.y+1)
    print('overlaping:', overlaping)
    print('clicked:', circle_id in overlaping)
    
    if circle_id in overlaping:
        canvas.moveto(circle_id, random.randint(0, 500-24), random.randint(0, 500-25))
    
    print('-----')

def on_item_click(event):
    print('on item click')
    
    print('event:', event)
    print('x, y :', event.x, event.y)

    canvas.moveto(circle_id, random.randint(0, 500-24), random.randint(0, 500-25))

    print('-----')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

canvas.bind('<Button-1>', on_canvas_click)

circle_id = canvas.create_oval(67, 58, 61+24, 58+25, width=3, fill="#ff0000")
canvas.tag_bind(circle_id, '<Button-1>', on_item_click)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Doc from old effbot.org: [The Tkinter Canvas Widget](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/canvas.htm), [Events and Bindings](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: Thank you so much Brother for your help the logic you provided it worked.